# multiple fields for one item in MySqli query that need to go into one textbox with php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am attempting to put the subjects of the books I have in my website.  I have a query in MySqli that will get me the information perfectly, except that most books have more than one subject listed for their isbn number.  Here is my query:

```
SELECT b.id,b.title, sss.title as subject 
from books b
LEFT JOIN book_subjects bs on b.id = bs.book
LEFT JOIN sub_subject ss on ss.id = bs.sub_subject
LEFT JOIN sub_sub_subject sss on bs.sub_sub_subject = sss.id
where b.isbn13 = 9780596515898
```

and the result set:

```
489282  JavaScript: The Missing Manual (Missing Manual Series)  Network Programming
489282  JavaScript: The Missing Manual (Missing Manual Series)  Programming Languages
489282  JavaScript: The Missing Manual (Missing Manual Series)  Web Programming / Development
```

How do I get it so all the subjects(Network Programming, Programming Languages etc.) are all in one field instead of three?  I would like it to look like:

```
489282  JavaScript: The Missing Manual (Missing Manual Series) Network Programming, Programming Language, Web Programming/ Developement
```

I can either try to do this in the query or with Php after the results are generated.  I did try

```
CONCAT(sss.title) as subject
```

but that threw an error on my query.  I am not sure if a foreach loop would work or not, so I figured I would ask for help before spending hours trying in vain.

Comment: what is your expected output? CONCAT should take at least multiple argument for concatenation i suppose. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT b.id,b.title, GROUP_CONCAT(sss.title) as subject 
from books b
LEFT JOIN book_subjects bs on b.id = bs.book
LEFT JOIN sub_subject ss on ss.id = bs.sub_subject
LEFT JOIN sub_sub_subject sss on bs.sub_sub_subject = sss.id
where b.isbn13 = 9780596515898
```